# cannot resolve symbol ThemeOverlay

Tags: android, xml

after an update to Android Studio I get this problen that 
cannot resolve symbol 'ThemeOverlay' of the lines.

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

it'll help me if u could tell me how to fix the problem.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with the SDK 28, change it to SDK 27 or change your code to:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

It worked for me.

Comment: how can i change the sdk?

Comment: go to Gradle scripts -> build.gradle (App) 

and change `compiledSdkVersion 28` to  **27**,

 `targetSdkVersion 28` to **27** 

and instead of for example ' implementation `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01`

use `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1`

Answer (score 1):

just follow these steps for api 21 to 28

1. close open project
2. delete it from recent
3. open project from location

problem solved